# How to calculate the Scattering Matrix for a Sentinel-1 image

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-1

How can we calculate the elements of the `scattering matrix` (`Spq` with `p` and `q` being the transmit/receive polarizations), for a `Sentinel-1` image?

Does the image have to be in a `Single-Look Complex (SLC)` format (contains complex values), in order to calculate the `scattering matrix`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the formulas that I was looking for in this article: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=1036007

These formulas obviously depend on the `fresnel reflection coefficients` which can be found here: https://earth.esa.int/documents/653194/656796/Rough_Surface_Scattering_Models.pdf